# Rails4: Passing non-forum data from front end to the back end, and processing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Ok. So I have a small XHR request where json is returned. On success the json is passed like this.

```
var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
myMainFunction(myArr);

function myMainFunction(arr) {
    var vShipTypeID = arr[0].victim.shipTypeID;
    }
```

I need to send *vShipTypeID* to rails. My goal is to be sending this value back to activerecord and the information returned will go within a js, or json file to the *respond_to* statement in the controller.

```
@shipName = InvType.find(vShipTypeID).name
```

Here's the main idea. The client sends out the ID of the ship to rails, and rails returns the ship's name.

I know how to make the Ajax request.

I don't know how to process the request on the server end. Meaning after rails receives the data, where do I find it, and how to I convert it to be usable so that I can make an activerecord statement out of the value I received from the client?

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle json requests in your controller check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119057/get-json-contents-from-ruby-on-rails-server-using-ajax) for details

for a quick example in your controller create a new action getnamefromid and call that controller from your client.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json  { render :json => @shipName }
end
```

Comment: That doesn't explain how I can make sure that "vShipTypeID" successfully makes it into the activerecord statement from the client.

Comment: You need to add a custom action, getnamefromid to ships controller and call that custom action from your client with the id and read the json response.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be defining an action on your ship controller and define a route to it for example define a route in your routes.rb

```
get "/ship/:id/getname" => "ship#getname"
```

in your `js` file

```
$.get( "/ship/"+vShipID+"/getname")
  .done(function(data) {
    alert( "Ship name: " + data.name );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  });
```

in you ship_controller.rb

```
class ship_controller <ApplicationController
     ....... #other methods
     def getname
         @shipname = Ship.find(params[:id]).name
         if request.xhr
            render :json => {name: @shipname} and return
         else
            redirect_to ship_path(params[:id])
         end
     end
     ........ #some other methods
end
```